# VS 2008 : Code Definition Window wrong symbol file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, symbols, definition, platform-sdk

I have installed both Microsoft Platform SDKs v6.0A and v7.0. Inside Visual Studio 2008 I include  that is defined to get this file from v7.0.

Beside that, when I use CDW (code definition window) to overview symbols, for example GUIDs by opening the "uuids.h" it opens the one that is included in SDK v6.0A instead of v7.0.

I cleaned solution, I double checked the VC++ dirs (for includes, libs etc) they are all set in the v7.0.

What's wrong here with CDW ? How to force CDW to see the v7.0 path instead of the old one ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "*Windows SDK Configuration Tool*" which gets installed with any SDK. When you start that tool, it shows you all the installed SDK's to choose from, and the one you choose is then used in VS2008.

PS : Check also "Windows SDK Configuration Tool May Report an Error When OS Display Format is not English" at  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2009/08/21/windows-sdk-configuration-tool-may-report-an-error-when-os-display-format-is-not-english.aspx